# Multiply vectors in a matrix by a matrix

Tags: matrix, rotation

I have a matrix of vectors e.g.

```
mat1 = Table[Table[RandomReal[1], 2], n, n];
```

which is actually a matrix of cartesian coordiantes `(x,y)`. I want to rotate the coordinate system multiplying each vector by a rotation matrix. I'm using

```
matRot = Map[RotationMatrix[3 Degree].# &, mat1, {2}];
```

However, this is very slow for larger matrices such as `n = 2048`. I believe there is a more efficient way.

Comment: `Map[RotationTransform[3. Degree], mat1, {2}]` is still slow but faster.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can actually use `Dot` directly. It works in unintuitive ways with tensors.

```
n = 1000;
mat1 = Table[Table[RandomReal[1], {2}], {n}, {n}];

matRot = Map[RotationMatrix[3 Degree].# &,  mat1, {2}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {79.8211, Null}

```
matRot2 = Map[RotationTransform[3. Degree], mat1, {2}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {9.04459, Null}

```
matRot3 = mat1.RotationMatrix[3 Degree]\[Transpose]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.072949, Null}

```
matRot == matRot2 == matRot3
```

> True

EDIT: While this is not what you asked, might I suggest you build `mat1` directly with `RandomReal`? Bottlenecks are probably elsewhere, but anyways.

```
SeedRandom[16];
mat1 = Table[Table[RandomReal[1], {2}], {n}, {n}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.638727, Null}

```
SeedRandom[16];
mat = RandomReal[1, {n, n, 2}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.015406, Null}

```
mat == mat1
```

> True

Comment: Using `3. Degree` makes it even faster (+1)

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I'm looking for! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
n = 1000;
mat1 = Table[Table[RandomReal[1], {2}], {n}, {n}];

matRot = Map[RotationMatrix[3 Degree].# &,  mat1, {2}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {110.570004, Null}

```
matRot2 = Map[RotationTransform[3. Degree], mat1, {2}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {13.946951, Null}

```
matRot == matRot2
```

> True